# How to fast in the Land of the Midnight Sun?

Tags: salat, sawm, ramadan

In tropical countries, we have a good proportion of day and night in 24 hour. So, praying and fasting is somewhat easy for us. In Bangladesh we fast, in most, for 16 hours. But in Sweden, it's becoming 18+.

I wonder what would happen if I go to the [polar regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Midnight_Sun) or a region near the polar regions, where the day and night are roughly as:

- A daytime for 20 hours.
- A daytime for 30 days. (I remember a movie named *30 days of night*)

So, my question is:

How do we fast in Ramadan, given the above day timings?

Answer (score 1):

> [T]hose who live close to the Arctic Circle, where they have continual night or continual day for several months, should look to the closest city to them where night and day are distinct in each twenty-four hour period, then they should do the five daily prayers based on the timing in that city. ([Reference](http://islamqa.com/en/13916))

I would add, same applies for fasting.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: if he knows best, how come he didn't know that eventually people would inhabit the polar regions and that the fasting regimen, as defined by Islam, is not applicable there ?